# Trying to install tkinter on Linux with a non-root account on python 3.6.8

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

I am trying to install tkinter on a Linux system with python 3.6.8 using ' pip3 install tkinter ' but got the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

So I then tried ' yum install python3-tkinter ' but was then notified that I do not have the root privileges in order to perform the command. Is there another method I can use to successfully install tkinter without yum or sudo?

Comment: Unfortunately, not that I know of. Your admin can't do it for you?

Comment: You might want to upgrade to at least Python 3.7, which includes tkinter in the standard library (so you wouldn't need to install it manually).